# How to intercept "Could not load file or assembly"?

Tags: c#, exception, clr

During testing of a **command line based** program I delibrately removed a DLL from the execution directory.  This of course caused the `Could not load file or assembly` exception to trigger when the program started, and dumped the raw exception details onto the command line:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'MyDLL, Version=1.2.3.14056, Culture
>   =neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a0932194e205074' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   MyApp.Program.Program.Main(String[] args)

I don't want the user to see these raw details, but I can't see how/where to catch this exception in order to sanitize the presented message.

So what is the best/accepted way to catch something like this?

Comment: use ex.Message maybe?

Comment: Have tried looking for a global UnhandledException event? I taught it was in AppDomain.CurrentDomain and you might be able to handle the Exception there. Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: May be using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is the solution? To catch all unhandled exceptions and show their messages in proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register to the Unhandled Exception handler and treat it like so:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler((x, y) =>
{
    var exception = y.ExceptionObject as Exception;

    if (exception is System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        Console.WriteLine("Please make sure the DLL is in the same folder.");
});
```

Make sure this event registration is executed before any reference to `MyDLL` in your code. A static constructor in `Program.cs` might be a good option.

Comment: I copied your code into `static Program()` and while it built I still got the same response.  But I'm going to try again with a different build.  Is it possible that being a command line app I don;t have an event queue running?

Comment: It worked once I added `var sender = x as object` to your code.  The main trick I was missing was creating a static constructor for the Program!

Comment: @PeterM Could you explain better what do you mean by "creating a stati constructor for the Program"? what did you actually did?

Comment: Since a static constructor executes its code before any instance of the class is created, it will register to the event above at the earliest possible point. You can google "static constructor" for more info about the syntax.